# Injecting a lot of dependencies in my controller

Tags: php, dependency-injection, controller, dependencies

Currently I am only injecting my `Request`, `Session` and `UserService` classes, and the rest I just instantiate in my code wherever I need them.

Now, I've learned to always utilize dependency injection to loosely couple my classes with it's dependencies. In that case, do I really need to inject all those 10 classes and specify them in my constructor parameters?

**Sign up controller** (simplified):

```
namespace Controllers;

use \vHttp\Request;
use \vHttp\Session;
use \Models\Services\User;
use \Libraries\Validator\Validator;
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\MaxChars;
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\Alpha;
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\Email;
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\Match;
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\MinChars;
use \Libraries\CryptoCharGen;

class SignUp extends Controller
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Session $session, UserService $userService)
    {
        parent::__construct($request, $userService);

        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function index() {
        ...
    }

    public function submit() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to inject dependencies for everything by default. Think about what functionality you might have to change in the future or mock with tests, and inject that functionality.

If you find yourself passing more than a few dependencies to a constructor, consider whether you have a class that has too many responsibilities. Consider if you can encapsulate the dependencies into a parameter object or find another way to cut down on that [long parameter list](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/long-parameter-list).

You have to decide which tradeoffs to make when using dependency injection or any other design pattern. On one hand, it may make your design more flexible and loosely coupled. On the other hand, do you really need that additional flexibility? By using a design pattern without a real need for it, you're risking wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking, in short no. You have to pass to the constructor only the parameters you *need* for your class. In this case, I think the validators can be used without passing them to the constructor:

```
use \Libraries\Validator\Rules\Email;

class Signup extends Controller
{
    private $emailValidator;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Session $session, UserService $userService)
    {
        parent::__construct($request, $userService);

        $this->session = $session;
        $this->emailValidator = new Email();
    }
}
```